# Kibana Dashboard Time filter option is not working

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dashboard, kibana

I have configured Kibana dashboard for expose elastic search data and seems default dashboard is working fine but Time range filter not working.

I did custom dashboard with specified my timestamp field also but still not working.

Can any one help to resolve this issue? Here are the fields,

```
 _id
 _index
 _type
 reported_date
 request
 request_id
 type
```

Here reported_date field is time stamp have value like reported_date":"2014-07-10 12:55:14.662731".

Sample Data

```
Field   Action  Value
_id             XoYvZW-PRwe5AxdamsCydw
_index          test
_type           teststatus
reported_date   2014-06-27 10:32:07.528156
request         /testapi/test
```

Comment: Show what your /index/type/_mapping looks like.  Chances are your mapping has reported_date as a string instead of a time.

Comment: @Alcanzar Added samples

Comment: Your time is in a format that ES isn't going to auto-recognize as a time, so you need to create a mapping that includes a [Date Mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the time zone of ElasticSearch in UTC so when you send the time of the test execution, convert it into the UTC.

I have done these changes in my java code, and it works for me, logic will remain the same

```
DateFormat formatterIST = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        formatterIST.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
        Date dateobj = new Date();
        Date date = formatterIST.parse(formatterIST.format(dateobj));
        System.out.println(formatterIST.format(date));

        DateFormat formatterUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        formatterUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // UTC timezone
        System.out.println(formatterUTC.format(date));
```